# Display Hindi language in flex mobile application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, hindi

I want to display Hindi language as a Label text in flex mobile application. I am using adobe flash builder 4.5

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to consider the following:

1. Use UTF-8 file encoding in your project.
2. Use a font which supports Hindi chars.

I do not really understand what is your problem, maybe you can update your question.

Comment: Thanx adrian for your prompt reply. I have to display hindi fonts in my spark label and spark button component.

Comment: just set the label property and take care you follow my points. For fonts check this https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=free+hindi+fonts&oq=free+hindi+fonts&fp=46767289fb1c4897

Comment: hello Adrian, I got success in displayong font in hindi in spark label, but in spark button I got only BOXES :(

Comment: Are you using bold or italic font on the button? It may be possible that you embedded only the normal font and not the bold and italic as well. (also I presume you are using the same font for both label and button).  I suggest you have a look at this link http://www.redcodelabs.com/2013/04/embed-fonts-in-flex-with-css/

Comment: <s:Button x="355" y="515" width="218" id="btn" label="परिचय"/> when I run this application I get only boxes nothing else. Please help me I am fed up of this.! Thanx in advance

Comment: I tested it and works fine for me. Make sure you use the same font family for both label and button. Please check again the above points.

Comment: Hello sir, I have deployed app on iPad but app in iPad even does not show hindi font in Label text also. :(

Comment: in this case you need to embed a font which supports Hindi like described in this url http://www.redcodelabs.com/2013/04/embed-fonts-in-flex-with-css/ . Use the fontFamily= "MyEmbeddedFont" ex: <s:Label text="hindiText" fontFamily= "MyEmbeddedFont" />